# How to put multiple lines of text in the same Bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add notes at the right side of each inputs. Here is the
[example](https://codepen.io/lennyy/pen/oNedLqN) I created with bootstrap layout.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <section class="content container-fluid">
      <form id="submitForm">
        <fieldset>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="userId" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">User</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <select class="form-control" id="userId">
                <option value="1">Alex</option>
                <option value="39">Kent</option>
                <option value="6">Nick</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5, small" style="padding-left: 18px">
              If your name is not available, please contact the Officer.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="purposeNames" class="col-md-1 col-form-label">Purpose</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" id="purposeNames" class="form-control" placeholder="Purpose" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-left: 18px">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12, small">
                  Feel free to select more than one purpose per ticket e.g. email + instant messaging. Such purpose combinations will only proportionally affect purpose statistics. Please do not use online time that was initially requested for purposes of the category
                  "Not affecting personal quota" (e.g. chores) also for checking personal emails, instant messaging etc. Instead, request separate internet access by selecting the desired purpose category e.g. email; instant messaging etc.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="userPassword" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5, small" style="padding-left: 18px">
              Please use combination of letter, symbol & number.
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem is when the screen width reduced, the row which has multiple lines doesn't behave properly. For instance:

**1. Label (Purpose) position changed:**

[image]

**2. No text padding:**

[image]

***Update:***

Found that the **1. Label (Purpose) position changed** issue is due to the col-md-1 of the purpose label. Should use col-sm instead. Heres the modified version:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <section class="content container-fluid">
      <form id="submitForm">
        <fieldset>
        <br>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="userId" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">User</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <select class="form-control" id="userId">
                <option value="1">Alex</option>
                <option value="39">Kent</option>
                <option value="6">Nick</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-5 small" style="padding-left: 3px">
              If your name is not available, please contact the Officer.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="purposeNames" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Purpose</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" id="purposeNames" class="form-control" placeholder="Purpose" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-5 small" style="padding-left: 3px">
              Feel free to select more than one purpose per ticket e.g. email + instant messaging. Such purpose combinations will only proportionally affect purpose statistics. Please do not use online time that was initially requested for purposes of the category
              "Not affecting personal quota" (e.g. chores) also for checking personal emails, instant messaging etc. Instead, request separate internet access by selecting the desired purpose category e.g. email; instant messaging etc.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="userPassword" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-5 small" style="padding-left: 3px">
              Please use combination of letter, symbol & number.
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now the only problem left is the text padding. Padding-left 3px is good when full screen but not when screen shrinks:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use padding-right: 3px at inputs solve my padding issue:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <section class="content container-fluid">
      <form id="submitForm">
        <fieldset>
        <br>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="userId" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">User</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6"  style="padding-right: 3px">
              <select class="form-control" id="userId">
                <option value="1">Alex</option>
                <option value="39">Kent</option>
                <option value="6">Nick</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-5 small">
              If your name is not available, please contact the Officer.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="purposeNames" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Purpose</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6"  style="padding-right: 3px">
              <input type="text" id="purposeNames" class="form-control" placeholder="Purpose" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-5 small">
              Feel free to select more than one purpose per ticket e.g. email + instant messaging. Such purpose combinations will only proportionally affect purpose statistics. Please do not use online time that was initially requested for purposes of the category
              "Not affecting personal quota" (e.g. chores) also for checking personal emails, instant messaging etc. Instead, request separate internet access by selecting the desired purpose category e.g. email; instant messaging etc.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="userPassword" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6"  style="padding-right: 3px">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-5 small">
              Please use combination of letter, symbol & number.
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have commas in your class attributes. This is invalid and results in the classes that follow not being applied. When they're removed (along with the nasty inline styles) it all works as expected.

The row nesting isn't even needed. I've removed that, along with the line break, which shouldn't be used for layout and apparently wasn't doing anything anyway.

Bootstrap drops inputs below labels by default for mobile (xs) so there's room for the inputs on narrow screens. I don't recommend changing that, but if you want to, simply use `col-xs-*`  instead of `col-sm-*` so you aren't ignoring the smallest breakpoint.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <section class="content container-fluid">
      <form id="submitForm">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="userId" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">User</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <select class="form-control" id="userId">
                <option value="1">Alex</option>
                <option value="39">Kent</option>
                <option value="6">Nick</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-5 small">
              If your name is not available, please contact the Officer.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="purposeNames" class="col-md-1 col-form-label">Purpose</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" id="purposeNames" class="form-control" placeholder="Purpose" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-5 small">
              Feel free to select more than one purpose per ticket e.g. email + instant messaging. Such purpose combinations will only proportionally affect purpose statistics. Please do not use online time that was initially requested for purposes of the category
              "Not affecting personal quota" (e.g. chores) also for checking personal emails, instant messaging etc. Instead, request separate internet access by selecting the desired purpose category e.g. email; instant messaging etc.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="userPassword" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-5 small">
              Please use combination of letter, symbol & number.
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about the commas. But your example still has the problem of "1. Label (Purpose) position changed" when the screen wide is reduced to about 60%.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
<div>
    <section class="content container-fluid">
   <form id="submitForm">
        <fieldset>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row mb-2">
            <label for="userId" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">User</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="userId">
                    <option value="1">Alex</option>
                    <option value="39">Kent</option>
                    <option value="6">Nick</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 small">
                If your name is not available, please contact the Officer.
            </div>
        </div>  
        
        <div class="form-group row mb-2">
            <label for="purposeNames" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Purpose</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" id="purposeNames" class="form-control" placeholder="Purpose"  />                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-left: 18px">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-12, small">
                    Feel free to select more than one purpose per ticket e.g. email + instant messaging.
                    Such purpose combinations will only proportionally affect purpose statistics.
                    Please do not use online time that was initially requested for purposes of the category "Not affecting personal quota"
                    (e.g. chores) also for checking personal emails, instant messaging etc.
                    Instead, request separate internet access by selecting the desired purpose category e.g. email; instant messaging etc.                  
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>          
        </div>  
        
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="userPassword" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 small" style="padding-left: 18px">
                Please use combination of letter, symbol & number.
            </div>
        </div>  
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer should include some explanation of the changes. Don't make us scrutinize line by line what you did.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment.
Anyway, using your example cause different padding sizes among the inputs & can't get rid of my problem "2. No text padding", see this: https://codepen.io/lennyy/pen/zYdaORz. 
Here is the update after I changed all last columns padding to "padding-left: 3px": https://codepen.io/lennyy/pen/JjyZPGJ.
Now it looks fine when full screen, but the problem "2. No text padding" still persist when screen width reduced.

Comment: @len, _delete_ your previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the text inside a div and add css property overflow: hidden

```
    <div class="col-sm-5, small" style="padding-left: 18px">
        <div class="sample">
            Feel free to select more than one purpose per ticket e.g. email + instant messaging.
            Such purpose combinations will only proportionally affect purpose statistics.
            Please do not use online time that was initially requested for purposes of the category "Not affecting personal quota"
            (e.g. chores) also for checking personal emails, instant messaging etc.
            Instead, request separate internet access by selecting the desired purpose category e.g. email; instant messaging etc.
        </div>              
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
      .sample
      {
          overflow: hidden;
      }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But still not right with the text padding size. I have to use "padding-left: 18px" at the col-sm-5 to prevent the "2. No text padding" problem. This cause the distance between the input & it notes too wide when in full screen. See my update: https://codepen.io/lennyy/pen/RwZyomX

Comment: Few changes needs to be done in your code sent.
Here is the codepen url :
https://codepen.io/allenjohnson8/pen/xxLjYjW

Comment: Your new example has the problem of "1. Label (Purpose) position changed" when the screen width is reduced to about 60%.